# Regex for validating a name of this particular format

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a solution in regex. I have a full name for which the allowed characters are a-z, A-Z, space and /,-.@'

Also it should not start with a blank character/space.

So basically the following names are accepted.

1. Anjith Sasindran
2. Anjith@ Sasindran'
3. Anjith
4. Anjith/,Sasi@n'ran
5. An-. Sasindr@

And the following are not

1. An%jith Sasindran
2. Anjit*) Sasindran

Basically anything other than the ones I listed above.

I'm not sure how to do the same. I've very little knowledge in regex b/w. So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
^[^\s][ A-Za-z-'@.,/]*$
```

- `^[^\s]` checks that there is no whitespace at the beginning
- `A-Za-z` accepts all the alphabets in the given string
- `-'@.,/` accepts only these special characters
- `*` matches 0 or more preceding token

Comment: What does the $ sign do at the end? Why can't the * be a +? The solution you offered works perfectly for my situation, but would like to know a bit more as you've given a good explanation.

Comment: Test it with `%` as input. It will tell you that it's a match. The [^\s]` means **any** character **except** a blank one.

Comment: @capt.swag ```$``` at the end means that it would accept those strings that ends with this regex condition. Better to understand would be as @amanin said, test it with your example ```An%jith Sasindran``` and it would still match the ```An``` part of it. Also  ```+``` sign would match 1 or more preceding token whereas ```*``` matches 0 or more. In these examples that you provided  ```*/+``` both would work, but you need to use it according to your situation

Answer (score 0):

With regular expressions, you can define classes of characters like the follwing:
`[\sa-zA-Z@\.,\-'/]`.

With that, you define one "allowed" character. You can specify a sequence of it by adding plus operator : `[\sa-zA-Z@\.,\-'/]+`.

Now, to avoid texts starting with blank character, you can create a character class with all wanted characters except spaces `[a-zA-Z@\.,\-'/]`.

So, now, the final regex is "any of the wanted characters except a blankspace, followed by any of wanted characters a certain number of times" : `[a-zA-Z@\.,\-'/][\sa-zA-Z@\.,\-'/]*`
With java, you must use Pattern class to apply regex checks on a string:

```java
var nameMatcher = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z@\\.,\\-'/][\\sa-zA-Z@\\.,\\-'/]*").asPredicate();
if (nameMatcher.test("Anjhit@")) System.out.println("Name match !");
```

You can get a lot of information with [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).